# How to dynamically pass db names with boxfuse deploying play framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework-2.3, cloudcaptain

I have been trying to deploy a play application which has a mysql back end , have  the db config  in application.conf , trying to build a  test conf 
 running below since i had a db created already 
`boxfuse run nimalist-api:1.0 -env=test -jvm.args=-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -dbtype=none`

But boxfuse was still creating a new database, so since the configuration in my play config was wrong the play application was not getting deployed

Is there a way :-

1. I can tell boxfuse not to create a db when deploying the play application

   2. Is there a way if boxfuse creates db, i can pass the db configs dynamically to my play application

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. You can tell Boxfuse to not create a DB by explicitly creating your app with `boxfuse create myapp -dbtype=none` (See https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/commandline/create)
2. When you let Boxfuse create the databases for you, Boxfuse will automatically configure your application in each environment to use the correct database instance for that environment (See https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/play)